# Typescript compile-time conditional for browser vs server code

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to share code between browser and server parts of a web app. It might be useful to have something like an `#if` conditional. Is there anything like that in Typescript?

For example:

```
interface Card {
    id: Uuid
    text: string
    created_dt: Date
}
```

One the server, `Uuid` is a type from a database library. On the browser I'll need to use something else.

Hypothetical code:

```
#if compiling_for_browser
type Uuid = somelib.Uuid
#else
type Uuid = database_lib.types.Uuid
#endif

interface Card ...
```

Comment: Why can't the frontend import the database library types?

Comment: I assumed that trying to import the Cassandra database driver (in my case) in the browser would not go well, because none of the physical reality behind the module exists in that environment. If it didn't crash, I'd also worry about downloading unnecessary code to the browser.

Comment: The frontend can import the types without having to use any of the code itself. As for downloading ... when you build all of the types should be erased so none of the type definitions should ship with the built code.

Comment: @ExplosionPills is correct if your `Uuid` is an interface, that will not exist in built code. Otherwise, no, see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3538

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is the most popular library implementing conditional compilation https://github.com/nippur72/ifdef-loader

The TypeScript team has not implemented it and doesn't seem to be moving quickly to do so, for my use (same use case, basically) I'm going to try some of the webpack conditional compilation items so I can build easily for web and react-native